# Is expressing XYTolerance in degrees an oxymoron?

Tags: coordinate-system, tolerance, precision-scale

**Given:** an ArcGIS featureclass whose spatialreference is a geographic coordinate system (GCS), and an XYTolerance expressed in decimal degrees.

**Find:** a way to union (i.e. dissolve) adjacent polygons together based on a common attribute, that maintains the highest level of precision without creating slivers between the resulting polygons.

**Assumption:** the original coordinates must have been surveyed/collected with a precision expressed in linear units (e.g. meters).

**The (only?) Solution:**

1. get the original xytolerance in linear (*not* angular) units from the data vendor, (e.g. meters)
2. Project the polygons (e.g. Albers).
3. Initialize an environment with linear XYTolerance
4. Union the polygons
5. (un)project the polygons back into GCS.

**Question:** *Is there some way to union GCS-based polygons without knowing the XYTolerance in linear units, and without projecting/unprojecting?*

And if not, could we conclude that XYTolerance expressed in decimal degrees is useless for unioning together polygons for datasets that extend into higher latitudes?

Is it necessary for vendors of such datasets to publish the original XYTolerance *expressed in linear units* for consumers to union together polygons without creating slivers?

Comment: What if the surveyors use GPS for gathering the original coordinates? Shouldn't they then report the tolerances in geocentric units? Could you give more details about the problem what you have, preferably with test data?

Comment: @user30184 it is my understanding that GPS accuracy is typically in linear units, such as shown in the chart here at [the naval postgraduate school website](https://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/gps/gpsacc.html).

Comment: This seems more like a discussion topic than a question.

Comment: My understanding is that natively GPS is dealing with geocentric coordinates http://what-when-how.com/gps/geocentric-earth-fixed-coordinate-systems-gps/ but the accuracy for example in HDOP and VDOP are converted into meters because it is more friendly for the GPS users. You are right than turning the accuracy into a single value in EPSG:4326 degrees does not work well near the poles. But I have thought that the purpose of https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/xy-tolerance.htm is to help to deal with rounding errors like ST_SnapToGrid in PostGIS.

Comment: @Vince, Granted, the title is click-baity, but I feel the question is legit: _Is there some way to union GCS polygons without knowing the XYTolerance in linear units, and without projecting/unprojecting?_

Comment: @user30184 Imagine a survey of two adjacent looking lots near the south pole.  The longitude of corner of lot A and lot B might have a longitude that differs by a degree, yet be only a few centimeters apart, while the latitude of opposite corners differs by, say,  0.01.  Setting XYTolerance to 1 degree would collapse both lots into zero-area polygons, right?

Comment: @user30184 oops, I just noticed PostGIS' [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) takes separate `sizeX` and `sizeY` args instead of just a single `size` arg.  So it looks like I can scale `sizeX` based on latitude of the collection of polygons I'm unioning .